# Liberty Runtime with JRE 7

Tags: java, ibm-cloud, websphere-liberty

I have an application that's running with JRE7 without any problems; however, I want to begin using JRE 8 for testing purposes.  Will I be able to test against JRE 8 without any problems and any idea when the JRE will be provided in the buildpack?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Due to planned JRE updates to the Liberty Buildpack and the potential for these updates to affect your application, I would encourage you to tailor your application for Java 8 as soon as possible.  You can test against JRE 8 by specifying the following environment variable:

```
$ cf set-env myapp JBP_CONFIG_IBMJDK "version: 1.8.+"
```

In fact, towards the end of August, **the default JRE will change from v7 to v8**.  If you're concerned about these changes, please see the article below regarding upcoming changes to the Liberty Runtime:

https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/2015/07/22/liberty-buildpack-updates-java-ee-7/

Comment: Thanks for your quick response!